# An alert() after $.post cause chrome hangs while works fine in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Sorry maybe this question is stupid (alert should be put in $.post's callback), but it's really confusing.

The following js code runs fine in FireFox, but cause Chrome hangs everytime.

```
$.post("main.php");
alert('hello');
```

The 'main.php' is just as simple as:

```
<?php
    echo 0;
?>
```

It works very well on FireFox(an alert window pops up immediately), while causes Google Chrome hangs for a quite long time (browser hanging for more than 20minutes and nothing shows at all).

If I change "alert('hello');" to "console.log('hay, I am back!');", however, it works for both FireFox and Chrome everytime.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try your `POST` request like this:

```
   $.post('main.php',{},function(response) 
    {
        alert("Success Yo!");
        console.log(response);  //check if you're getting the correct response from server
    }).error(function(){
        alert("Oops error");
    });
```

Comment: Yes, Aditya. Should do in that way.  But just confusing why it can work in FF but not in Chrome.  I just want to know, although using callbacks is the right way, is the way using alert() after $.post wrong?

Comment: When you write `alert('Something')`, the page execution stops and waits for your approval to continue , which was interfering with your `POST` request . Different browsers have different ways of handling this, that's the reason you were facing problem in `Chrome` but not in `FF`.

Comment: Understand. When I pressed "ENTER" key on the hanged web page, which possibly dismissed unshown alert window, the web page get back to alive immediately.   Seems Chrome handles this scenario in a different way from FF and IE10.  Thank you Aditya!